# does any usertest / screen recording software work with meteor?

Tags: meteor, user-testing

I'm trying to better understand user experience by seeing what users are doing on the site. There are various tools out there that will work to track the clickstream, and record pageviews, generating heatmaps etc.

However, they don't seem to work with meteor. Since meteor is not even using ajax - it's data over sockets - and I think the tools do not support this newfangled magic.

I was wondering if anyone has found a remote recording/click tracking tool that works with meteor?

For example:
- http://www.luckyorange.com
who have a [note here about](http://help.luckyorange.com/knowledgebase/articles/129589-dealing-with-dynamic-ajax-rich-pages) hooking into the browsers XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open﻿ but that's not gonna work with meteor and more socket level protocols, it seems.

mouseflow.com also just recorded a white screen.
crazyegg.com doesn't even support ajax.

There are some other mobile specific tools like:
- http://www.uxrecorder.com/
but that would require native SDKs. First off I just want to put this up for the web.

There's one company https://lookback.io/explore who actually develop their desktop site in meteor, but they are mobile/iOS only :(

it's quite time consuming to try these out so it would be good to know anyone else's experience, eg:
http://www.getapp.com/alternatives/mouseflow-application

How are people doing remote usability testing of meteor sites?

Answer (score 2):

Mouseflow does work with Meteor, though you might need to enable some extra features in the Mouseflow dashboard. The most notable would be the enhanced tracking mode, Session Support, which is necessary to track Meteor pages.

Additionally, it might be necessary to block some scripts from being loaded in playback, but that is something the Mouseflow crew can easily do from their end, if you contact them through the support links.

Disclaimer: I work for Mouseflow

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the tools, I found inspectlet

http://www.inspectlet.com/

and had no problems integrating that with meteor. It's a new tool and seems to be designed from the start with Single Page apps in mind. Overall their tool is quite minimal but does the job really well and seems to work flawlessly with meteor. They're also a startup and were very responsive on other questions.

I created a small wrapper meteor package around Inspectlet and other a few other useful metrics toolkits, if anyone is interested I'll publish it to atmosphere (let me know here).